# Unable to get message array from the Thread List While using gmail Query -queryForUsersThreadsList

Tags: ios, objective-c, gmail-api

We are working on gmail App.

When we are fetching the thread list using query - "queryForUsersThreadsList"

We are unable to get the **message list for a thread**.

Please find the code bellow

```
 - (void)fetchAllMails {
[self showLoader];
GTLQueryGmail *query = [GTLQueryGmail queryForUsersThreadsList];
NSString * strQuery = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"priorityQuery"];
query.q = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ OR %@ ",strQuery,[DataManager sharedManager].contactString];
[self.service executeQuery:query
                  delegate:self
         didFinishSelector:@selector(displayThreadListWithTicket:finishedWithObject:error:)];
}


- (void)displayPriorityMessageListWithTicket:(GTLServiceTicket *)ticket
                      finishedWithObject:(GTLGmailListThreadsResponse *)emailsResponse error:(NSError *)error
{
if (error == nil)
{
    //[self hideLoader];
    NSMutableString *labelString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    nxtPageToken = emailsResponse.nextPageToken;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:emailsResponse.nextPageToken forKey:@"priorityNextPageToken"];
    NSLog(@"%@",emailsResponse.threads);
    for(GTLGmailThread *thread in emailsResponse.threads){
        NSLog(@"historyId --- %@",thread.historyId);
        NSLog(@"messages ----- %@",thread.messages);
        NSArray *arrMessage = thread.messages;
        NSLog(@"snippet ---- %@",thread.snippet);
        NSLog(@"identifier --- %@",thread.identifier);
    }
}
```

so above we are getting **arrMessage = nil;**

console

messages -----

here is the responce bellow :-

```
{
nextPageToken = 06476267169132000279;
resultSizeEstimate = 250;
threads =     (
            {
        historyId = 153697;
        id = 1546076d7fd73764;
        snippet = "Hi , mobile";
    },
            {
        historyId = 153626;
        id = 15460736289d4f7d;
        snippet = "";
    },
           );
 }
```

The Thread dictionary in above json do not contain the key message i.e message array

Any suggestions.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe the problem is how you set your code. Try to check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/list#request) if it can help you. You can see/check here some code example on how to use `Users.threads: list`

Comment: please look above i have added the responce. I had used the same api as mentioned in doc